# How do I multiply lines of Ruby code in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to return a HTML string value from Ruby block in Haml code:

```
!= my_helper_method 'some_div_id' do
     #{
          <<-HTML
                %div
                  %b
                    some data:
                  %span#some_id123
                %div
                  %b
                    some data2:
                  %span#some_id123224
            HTML
        }
```

Notice that the string between `#{ ... }` might be pretty long. This code throws an "`Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal`." exception.

I tried different ways but there was no luck.

Your opinions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you’re trying to do here, you need to use the [`capture_haml` helper method](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method).

Something like this:

```haml
!= my_helper_method 'some_div_id' do
  - capture_haml do
    %div
      %b
        some data:
      %span#some_id123
    %div
      %b
        some data2:
      %span#some_id123224
```

`capture_haml` evaluates the Haml, but doesn’t write the generated HTML to the output buffer as normal, instead it returns it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`haml_tag`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method).

That's the way I've always done complex helpers that put out lots of Haml.  Combine it with `haml_concat` for your multi-line Ruby code.